# jQuery highlight background base on cell value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

A record with new and old price value,
if new price is different to old one, and highlight the record.

I want to use "setTimeout" function,and the highlight effects will disappear after 10s. How can I highlight the table rows base on values?

I use the jQuery-UI framework.

```
$(function(){
   setTimeout(change(), 3000);   
});

function change(){
  $(".table-striped").find("tr").each(function () {
    $("td").filter(function() {
      return $(this).text().indexOf("200") != -1;
    }).parent().toggleClass("highlight",5000).removeClass("highlight");
  });
}
```

```
<table class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>New Price</th>
       <th>Old Price</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>200</td>
       <td>1000</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>1000</td>
       <td>1000</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

```
.highlight {
       background: red !important;
       color: green !important;
   }
```

[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x2jrU/92/ for the fade out

Comment: @AkshayMulgavkar good, but I want the effects with background color blinking and highlight :P

Comment: which technology you are using for print table values ?

Comment: I use  jQuery UI framework

Comment: I have solved your issue with jquery please check my answer.

Comment: @XIANYU Does that worked for you ?

Comment: @XIANYU could you explain why you accepted the other answer? His code doesn't provide any smooth blinking effect, it only toggles the background-color which is a nightmare for the eyes, in the other hand mine uses jquery ui's built in highlight function as you mentionned you're using jquery ui.

Comment: According to the principles of stack overflow,I have to choose the better solution in the correct scenerio.

Comment: @XIANYU absolutely, you are free to accept what was best for you but I was just curious to know why you find the other one to be a better fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? I made it highlight using jquery ui's "highlight" [effect](https://api.jqueryui.com/effect/) with a timeout of 10 seconds as you wished.

Code below :

```js
$(function(){
    var elementToHighlight = '';
$(".table-striped tbody tr").each(function(i, el) {
 if ($(el).children(':first').html() != $(el).children(':last').html()) {
  if (i == $(".table-striped tbody tr").length - 1) {
   elementToHighlight += '.table-striped tbody > :eq(' + $(el).children(':first').parent().index() + ')';
        } else {
            elementToHighlight += '.table-striped tbody > :eq(' + $(el).children(':first').parent().index() + '), ';
        }
 } 
});   
   if (elementToHighlight.substr(-2) == ', ') {
    elementToHighlight = elementToHighlight.substr(0, elementToHighlight.length-2)
   }
   var blink = setInterval(function(){
       $(elementToHighlight).effect('highlight', {color: 'red'}, 1000);
      }, 1000);
  setTimeout(function() {
     clearInterval(blink);
    }, 10000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>New Price</th>
       <th>Old Price</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>200</td>
       <td>1000</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>1000</td>
       <td>1000</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>400</td>
       <td>1000</td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>500</td>
       <td>500</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>700</td>
       <td>700</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>200</td>
       <td>900</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I just edited my last code to take in case the prices match, this is the solution you're looking at!

Comment: Well, Ronak’s response was quickly,and  he point out you didn't match the price issues. For the better StackOverflow community, eventually I choosed you tcj' solution

Answer (score 1):

I have solved your issue with jquery please check my answer.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('tbody tr').each(function( i, val){
    var nprice = $(this).children('.new_price').html();
    var oprice = $(this).children('.old_price').html();
    
    if(nprice != oprice){
      $(this).addClass('divtoBlink');
      //$(this).children('td').css('background-color','red');
    }
  });
  
  setInterval(function () {
      $(".divtoBlink").css("background-color", function () {
          this.switch = !this.switch
          return this.switch ? "red" : ""
      });
  }, 100);
  
  setInterval(function () {
      $('tr').removeClass('divtoBlink').css('background-color','white');
  }, 5000)

});
```

```css
.divtoBlink {
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#627BAE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Id#</th>
            <th>Session Eamil</th>
            <th>Login Url</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>New Price</th>
            <th>Old Price</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center">@counter11</td>
                    <td>@item.SessionEmail11</td>
                    <td>@item.LoginUrl11</td>
                    <td>@item.CreatedAt11</td>
                    <td>Failed11</td>
                    <td class="new_price">200</td>
                   <td class="old_price">1000</td>
            
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center">@counter12</td>
                    <td>@item.SessionEmail12</td>
                    <td>@item.LoginUrl12</td>
                    <td>@item.CreatedAt12</td>
                    <td>Failed12</td>
                    <td class="new_price">1000</td>
                    <td class="old_price">1000</td>
               
                </tr>
           </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I wanna the effects with "ackground color blinking" and "setTimeout" function. I have no idea. :(

Comment: but you posted different table in question.

Comment: This will resolve your issue check my above modified code.

Comment: thanks for your answer, one more thing, Will the effects disappear after n seconds likes   jQuery-UI effect()?

Comment: Maybe 5 or 10 seconds. It is a variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193867/discussion-between-ronak-chauhan-and-xian-yu).

Comment: But The answer you accepted does not have criteria of matching new price and old price. @XIANYU